# wxWidgets Compiling MinGW - Error 1 & Error 2

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks, mingw32

I'm trying to compile wxWidgets (latest stable build 2.8.12) with a working bin copy of MinGW from my installation of Code::Blocks. I've tried setting the system environment variables as well as the normal build commands and the unicode ones, all of them give me [clean] Error 1 and/or [clean] Error 2.

This is what happens when I try doing a normal build via  **mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc clean**

```
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\build\msw> mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc clean
if exist gcc_mswd\*.o del gcc_mswd\*.o
if exist gcc_mswd\*.d del gcc_mswd\*.d
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxregexd.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxregexd.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxzlibd.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxzlibd.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxpngd.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxpngd.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxjpegd.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxjpegd.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxtiffd.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxtiffd.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxexpatd.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxexpatd.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28
d_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxbase28d_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxbase
28d_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxbase28d_net_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wx
base28d_net_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d_net.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d
_net.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d_net.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d
_net.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_core_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wx
msw28d_core_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_core.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_
core.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_core.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_
core.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_adv_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxm
sw28d_adv_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_adv.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_a
dv.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_adv.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_a
dv.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_media_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\w
xmsw28d_media_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_media.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d
_media.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_media.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d
_media.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxbase28d_odbc_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\w
xbase28d_odbc_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d_odbc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28
d_odbc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d_odbc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28
d_odbc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_dbgrid_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\
wxmsw28d_dbgrid_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_dbgrid.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28
d_dbgrid.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_dbgrid.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28
d_dbgrid.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_html_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wx
msw28d_html_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_html.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_
html.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_html.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_
html.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_qa_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxms
w28d_qa_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_qa.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_qa
.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_qa.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_qa
.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxbase28d_xml_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wx
base28d_xml_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d_xml.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d
_xml.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d_xml.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase28d
_xml.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_xrc_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxm
sw28d_xrc_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_xrc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_x
rc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_xrc.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_x
rc.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_aui_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxm
sw28d_aui_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_aui.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_a
ui.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_aui.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_a
ui.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_richtext_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_li
b\wxmsw28d_richtext_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_richtext.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw
28d_richtext.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_richtext.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw
28d_richtext.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxmsw28d_gl_gcc_custom.dll del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\wxms
w28d_gl_gcc_custom.dll
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_gl.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_gl
.a
if exist ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_gl.a del ..\..\lib\gcc_lib\libwxmsw28d_gl
.a
mingw32-make.exe -C ..\..\samples -f makefile.gcc LINK_DLL_FLAGS="-shared" LINK_
MODULE_FLAGS="-shared" CC="gcc" CXX="g++" CFLAGS="" CXXFLAGS="" CPPFLAGS="" LDFL
AGS="" CPP="gcc -E" SHARED="0" WXUNIV="0" UNICODE="0" MSLU="0" BUILD="debug" DEB
UG_INFO="default" DEBUG_FLAG="default" MONOLITHIC="0" USE_GUI="1" USE_HTML="1" U
SE_MEDIA="1" USE_XRC="1" USE_AUI="1" USE_RICHTEXT="1" USE_OPENGL="0" USE_ODBC="0
" USE_QA="0" USE_EXCEPTIONS="1" USE_RTTI="1" USE_THREADS="1" USE_CAIRO="0" USE_G
DIPLUS="0" OFFICIAL_BUILD="0" VENDOR="custom" WX_FLAVOUR="" WX_LIB_FLAVOUR="" CF
G="" CPPUNIT_CFLAGS="" CPPUNIT_LIBS="" RUNTIME_LIBS="dynamic" GCC_VERSION="3" cl
ean
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/samples'
if exist .\*.o del .\*.o
if exist .\*.d del .\*.d
mingw32-make.exe -C access -f makefile.gcc LINK_DLL_FLAGS="-shared" LINK_MODULE_
FLAGS="-shared" CC="gcc" CXX="g++" CFLAGS="" CXXFLAGS="" CPPFLAGS="" LDFLAGS=""
CPP="gcc -E" SHARED="0" WXUNIV="0" UNICODE="0" MSLU="0" BUILD="debug" DEBUG_INFO
="default" DEBUG_FLAG="default" MONOLITHIC="0" USE_GUI="1" USE_HTML="1" USE_MEDI
A="1" USE_XRC="1" USE_AUI="1" USE_RICHTEXT="1" USE_OPENGL="0" USE_ODBC="0" USE_Q
A="0" USE_EXCEPTIONS="1" USE_RTTI="1" USE_THREADS="1" USE_CAIRO="0" USE_GDIPLUS=
"0" OFFICIAL_BUILD="0" VENDOR="custom" WX_FLAVOUR="" WX_LIB_FLAVOUR="" CFG="" CP
PUNIT_CFLAGS="" CPPUNIT_LIBS="" RUNTIME_LIBS="dynamic" GCC_VERSION="3" clean
DNS server not authoritative for zone.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [clean] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/samples'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [clean] Error 2

C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\build\msw>
```

Comment: The error says "DNS server not authoritative for zone".  Is there resource that is referenced via the network?

Comment: You obviously have something wrong with your installation, there is no way running make should result in *DNS* errors.

Comment: I was using the MinGW bin from my Code::Blocks installation. I just now downloaded MinGW normally. I'm still getting an error. Jesus christ.

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476533/error-while-compiling-wxwidgets-2-8-12-on-mingw-with-gcc-4-8-1                                                          Kind of solves my problem by presenting a new one, but it's progress.

Answer (score 2):

You may have better luck using the commands I used to compile it:

```
cd C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\build\msw
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 USE_OPENGL=1
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 USE_OPENGL=1
pause
```

You can see that I have not used the clean command. I have never really needed it. What I do is, if I want to change the compilation options, I delete the folder and re-extract it from a fresh download. It may not be the best approach, but no clean needed!

A brief explanation of these settings:

- You should do both a build with debug and release. The debug build
  will help you to debug your code, but it will produce larger (and
  slower) executables. The release build will produce faster and
  smaller executables, but without debugging options.
- `SHARED=0` indicates a static build (that is, the library will be
  included inside your .exe). If you prefer to use separate .dll
  files, change it to `SHARED=1`.
- `MONOLITHIC=0` indicates that the library will be divided in several
  components, and you will have to choose which ones to include.
  Setting it to `MONOLITHIC=1` will cause the library to be built as a
  single massive file, which you would include. That is easier, but
  takes longer to link. If you choose to use `MONOLITHIC=1`, you should also add the
  option `CXXFLAGS="-fno-keep-inline-dllexport"` to prevent a problem
  with memory (it uses too much memory when compiling the library).
- `UNICODE=1` allows you to use non-english characters in your
  application. You should enable it.
- `USE_OPENGL=1` is only needed if you intend to use OpenGL. I prefer it.

On a final note, for this to work, you should have the folder `MinGW\bin` in your `PATH` environment variable (which I guess you already have).

Comment: Doing it that way gets me mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswud\wx\msw\rcdefshl Error 1